# MPMoviePlayerController causing parent view to not be released ARC

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, mpmovieplayercontroller

My project uses ARC. I want to play a movie when a button is pressed. Currently my code brings up a movie player and plays the movie properly. Once the MPMoviePlayerController view is dismissed it goes back to the original view. If I hit the back button on the original view it is not deallocated and remains in memory. If I never press the button to play the movie, it is deallocated properly.

Declared in .h

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerViewController * moviePlayerController;
```

To bring up the movie in .m:

```
 -(IBAction)playMovie:(NSURL *) theURL
{

    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:movieTrailerURL];
    self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

    [moviePlayerController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    //moviePlayerController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                             object:nil];

    [self presentViewController:moviePlayerController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

When the movie is dismissed either by ending or the done button being pressed this is called

```
- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    NSLog(@"I am in movie playback complete!!!");


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:nil];

  // [moviePlayerController.moviePlayer pause];
   // moviePlayerController.moviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime = -1;
   // [moviePlayerController.moviePlayer stop];
   // moviePlayerController.moviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime = -1;
    //[moviePlayerController.moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
   // [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
   // [moviePlayerController.moviePlayer release];


}
```

I have tried every combination of the commented out parts to try and get my moviePlayerController to release from memory so that the parent view will release and deallocate.

Comment: In `moviePlaybackComplete:`, try `self.moviePlayerController = nil;`. If that doesn't help, use the Allocations part of Instruments and see what is keeping hold of your view controller.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you, this helped. It seems my real problem is when the movie player is dismissed the "viewDidAppear" method is being called twice...I have no idea why...in here an NStimer is being set twice and keeping hold of my view controller. Any idea why these methods are being called twice?

Answer (score -1):

You are allocating the property with the self.propertyname it will change the retain count to "2" Because its retain count also increased by 1 when it @synthesize in .m class. so try to allocate the property by without self or just take it as global variable not a property.